# Get inner text to the before lastchild element

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have the following example, where I'm trying to extract the inner text for "a" element , which is a child of "i" element located before the last child of the list.

Example:

```html
<div class="lms-pagination" id="lms-pagination">    
 <ul>      
        <li class="disabled">
          <span class="current prev">Previous page</span>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <span class="current en-lang">1</span>
        </li>        
        <li>
          <a data-page="1" class="page-link en-lang">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a data-page="2" class="page-link en-lang">3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">...</span></li>
        <li>
          <a data-page="17" class="en-lang">18</a> <!-- Try to extract 18 in this example -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#1" class="next">Next page</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use something like

```
                    lastPage = await newPage.$$eval('#lms-pagination>ul>li:nth-child(???)>a', el => el.innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript:=

```js
function myFunction() {
  var list = document.getElementById("myList").lastChild.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;

  var items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var lastchild = items[items.length - 2].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = lastchild;
}
```

```html
<p>Example list:</p>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coffee22</li>
  <li>Tea22</li>
  <li>Coffee33</li>
  <li>Tea33</li>
</ul>
<p>Click the button to get the HTML content of the list's last child node.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>
</script>
```

Using jQuery:=

```js
alert($("li:nth-last-of-type(2)").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lms-pagination" id="lms-pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="disabled">
      <span class="current prev">Previous page</span>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <span class="current en-lang">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-page="1" class="page-link en-lang">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-page="2" class="page-link en-lang">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">...</span></li>
    <li>
      <a data-page="17" class="en-lang">18</a>
      <!-- Try to extract 18 in this example -->
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#1" class="next">Next page</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @aishawarya, anyway to approach that with puppeteer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get second last child value like this. 
`$("li").eq(-2).text()`